# undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass - Comment Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am displaying the date when a comment is published:

```
<%= comment.created_at.strftime("%d %b %Y") %>
```

This works, except if the comment is not filled out correctly, and is submitted. If this occurs I get the error: `undefined method`strftime' for nil:NilClass` instead of my comment validations.

How to fix this, I am not sure?

Here's my code:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, `:email, :website, :body, :url))`


   if @comment.errors.any?
  render "posts/show"
else
   redirect_to post_path(@post)
   end
end


def destroy
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    redirect_to post_path(@post)

    end


end




 class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base


belongs_to :post

validates_format_of :email, :with => /@/
validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5}
validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5}
validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5}


def gravatar_url
    stripped_email = email.strip
    downcased_email = stripped_email.downcase
    hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(downcased_email)
    default_url = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mirror-communications/assets/download.jpg"

    "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}"
end 


end 


<!-- Post Comments Partial -->
<li>                                    
                <article class="comment">                                           
                <div class="user-avatar">                                               
                <%= image_tag comment.gravatar_url %>                                                   
                </div>
                <div class="comment-content">
                <h5 class="name"><%= comment.name %></h5>
                <div class="comment-meta comment-reply">
                <span class="post-date"><%= comment.created_at.strftime("%d %b %Y") %></span>/<span class="comment-reply-link"><%= link_to comment.website.try(:remove, /.*\/\//), url_for(comment.website), target: '_blank', class: "comment-reply"  %></span>  
                </div>
                <p><%= comment.body %></p>
                </div>
                </article>

<!-- Form Partial -->
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>

<% if @comment && @comment.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> Your comment could not be submitted:</h2>
    <ul>
  <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
<form class="comment-form">
<div class="row">
<div class="column width-4">
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-name form-element", placeholder: "Name*", :tabindex => 1 %> 
</div>

 <div class="column width-4">
 <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-email form-element", placeholder: "Email* (not displayed)", :tabindex => 3 %> 
</div>

 <div class="column width-4">
  <%= f.url_field :website, class: "form-website form-element", placeholder: "Website", :tabindex => 4 %> 
</div>
</div>


  <div class="row">
  <div class="column width-12">
  <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-message form-element", placeholder: "Message*", :tabindex => 5  %> 


  <%= f.submit class: "form-submit button medium bkg-black bkg-hover-turquoise color-white color-hover-white no-margin-bottom" %>

</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<% end %>

<!-- Posts Show -->`

   <div class="post-comments">
  <h3 class="comments-title">
  <% if @post.comments.count < 2 %>
  <%= @post.comments.count %> Comment</h3>
  <% else %>
  <%= @post.comments.count %> Comments</h3>
  <% end %> 
  <div class="comments">
  <ul class="comment-list">

    <%= render @post.comments %>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate about "f the comment is not filed out correctly, and is submitted" ? How are those comments created? How do they persist in your database?

Comment: try this, comment.created_at.strftime("%d %b %Y") if comment.created_at.present?

Comment: @bgilbank, Can you explain the context when the comment is not created properly? If the validations on the comment pass, the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields in the comment record will be automatically populated. ie. If the comment exists, you can display the `created_at` field. It looks like `comment` is `nil` in your view. Try to find why its nil.

Comment: @bgilbank, I think you have not populated local variable comment properly.

Comment: @kiddorails Arun Kumar basically a user just presses submit without filling out any form fields.

Comment: @bgilbank, you should probably add `validations` to the model to avoid users from creating invalid records.

Comment: @ArunKumar what additional validations would your recommend? Thanks

Comment: @Navin your solution worked thank you! I was also displaying recent posts in my sidebar incorrectly, which was another reason why my error was occuring. I had `<% @posts.each do |post| %>, when I should of had <% Post.all.each do |post|  %>`

Comment: Great, if your issue is solved I will convert my comments into an answer please accept it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not populated local variable comment properly.
 try this,

```
 comment.created_at.strftime("%d %b %Y") if comment and comment.created_at
```